# rmagick does not cause data loss when saving as jpeg

Tags: rmagick

I want to write a script with rmagick, that re-saves an image x-times to demonstrate the data loss caused by jpeg.

Unfortunately there is only data loss while saving the first time.
All the other times, the image seems not to be compressed any further.

I tried to set the object to null, to start the Garbage Collector after every cyle, but all this had no effect. The images were compressed only once.

I'm posting my code below. It would be very helpfull to get any hints how to do this, to get the image compressed with every save-cycle.

```
$i = 1
$j=$i+1

$num = 700

while $i < $num  do

   puts $i

   erstes="%03d" % $i
   puts erstes
   ziel="%03d" % $j
   puts ziel
img = Image.read(o#{erstes}.jpeg").first
img.rotate!(90)
img.write("o#{ziel}.jpeg"){ self.quality = 50 }
img.destroy!
img = nil
GC.start

$i +=1
$j=$i+1
end
```

Comment: Did you manage to find why? I happen to have the same problem...